# Computing harmonic series for very large N (arbitrary precision problems)

Tags: julia, precision, arbitrary-precision

This is a followup question to [a previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52936189/julia-parallelism-distributed-slower-than-serial) I made.

I'm trying to compute the Harmonic series to very large terms, however when comparing to log(n)+γ I'm not getting the expected error.

I suspect the main problem is with the `BigFloat` julia type.

```
harmonic_bf = function(n::Int64)
    x=BigFloat(0)
    for i in n:-1:1
        x += BigFloat(1/i)
    end
    x
end
```

For example it is well known that the lower bound for the formula: H_n - log(n) - γ is 1/2/(n+1).
However, this holds for n=10^7 then fails for n=10^8.

```
n=10^8
γ = big"0.57721566490153286060651209008240243104215933593992"
lower_bound(n) = 1/2/(n+1)

>>> harmonic_bf(n)-log(n)-γ > lower_bound(BigFloat(n))
false
```

It's driving me crazy, I can't seem to understand what is missing... `BigFloat` supossedly should get arithmetic precision problems out of the way, however it seems not to be the case.

Note: I tried with BigFloat with unset precision and with 256 bits of precision.

Comment: Side note: write `function harmonic_bf(n::Int) ... end` to define a function. What you are doing defines a variable holding a function object (and looks like R).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to make sure that you use `BigFloat` everywhere. First in your function (notice that `BigFloat(1/n)` is not the same as `1/BigFloat(i)`):

```
function harmonic_bf(n::Int64)
    x=BigFloat(0)
    for i in n:-1:1
        x += 1/BigFloat(i)
    end
    x
end
```

and then in the test (notice `BigFloat` under `log`):

```
julia> harmonic_bf(n)-log(BigFloat(n))-γ > lower_bound(BigFloat(n))
true
```

Comment: Wonderful! I will admit the cluelessness of not using BigFloat inside log, however I'm more interested in the difference between `BigFloat(1/i)` and `1/BigFloat(i)`.

Comment: Check out `BigFloat(1/10^10)` vs `1/BigFloat(10^10)` to see the difference.